# Communication Theory - Basic Transmission Errors

Tags: communication

I have a question regarding some basic transmission error:

[image]

My confusion is with the solution to combat errors (transmit each frame 3 times). I would have though that the probability of receiving a bad frame now would be the probability of each frame being in error and since they are all independant it would be N^3pB^3 but that's incorrect apparently. I don't know why.

Comment: Think about this: The main purpose of sending the same frame/packet several times is so that the receiver can compare them.

Comment: Probability of a frame error is \$p_F=1-(1-p_B)^N\$.  For \$p_B \ll 1\$ this is close to \$N p_B\$, but not exactly the same.

Comment: The probability of a frame error when you have three frames in hand is entirely dependent on how you're decoding frames.  If you're doing bit-by-bit majority voting, as @mike65535 assumes, then you should try working out the probabilities of a decoding error for each of the eight combinations (no errors, correct, correct, error, correct, error, correct, etc.).  Then add 'em up, and see what you get.